# How to get width value of an element with clientWidth?

Tags: javascript, width, console.log

I am not able to return the value of the width of an element.

```
let dimensionPopup1 = popup.getElementsByTagName("img");
console.log(dimensionPopup1.clientWidth);
```

It's returning me "undefined" in the console. Same with offsetWidth, scrollWidth, and width.
When I check dimensionPopup1 in my console, I see all the elements and their values. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array, so you need to access the individual items... you won't get things like `offsetWidth` from the array

Comment: Alright. Thanks, I think I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an array of elements, so you must access the individual elements within the array to get to their properties.

For example...

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, x => console.log(x.clientHeight));
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B<br/>B</div>
<div>C<br/>C<br/>C</div>
```